# Convert comma separated array representation to list of elements

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin I have a string which contains an array of integer elements, represented as below

```
[3481, 3457, 3445, 3443, 3129, 3114]
```

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) I see that kotlin has a `joinToString` function, useful to transform a list of integers into the string above

```kotlin
val numbers = listOf(3481, 3457, 3445, 3129, 3114)
println(numbers.joinToString()) // 3481, 3457, 3445, 3129, 3114
println(numbers.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]")) // [3481, 3457, 3445, 3129, 3114]
```

Unfortunately I can't find the dual function "unjoin to list" from the documentation, so I came up into a quite rough solution, using a combination of `replace`, `split` and `trim`:

```kotlin
fun String.toIntList(): List<Int> {
    val elements = this
        .replace("[", "")
        .replace("]", "")
        .split(",")
    return elements.map { it.trim().toInt() }
}
```

Is there any `joinToString()` dual in kotlin or an elegant way to do the conversion to a list?

Comment: I don't think there's a special kotlin way for this unless you treat that `String` as a JSON list of `Int`s and wrap it in a valild format. Your solution might be one of the best ways to do it. Alternatively, you could take a `substring` skipping the first and the last character (the braces) instead of two `replace` operations.

Comment: +1 to deHaar. Also in your code, you can use `.removeSurrounding("[", "]")` instead of the 2 replace calls. You can also make the whole fun a one-liner `fun String.toIntList() = removeSurrounding("[", "]").split(",").map { it.trim().toInt() }`

Comment: I'd just do something like this ``text.slice(1..text.length-2).split(", ").map(String::toInt)`` (you can split on the actual comma-space string, no need to trim)